# How to save javascript current_time to Rails model?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application, but I got stuck on the following issue:
In my application Users watch Videos and can make Comments on them. I use Javascript to get the current_time from the video to display it underneath the videoplayer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('video').bind('timeupdate',function(){
    var current_time = $('video')[0].currentTime;
    console.log(current_time);
    $('#current_time').html('Current time: ' + formatTime(current_time));
  });
});
```

How can I save this current_time as an attribute to the Comment when a User hits the comment button and adds a new comment?
My goal is to display comments tied to a specific time in the video.

Comment: You can use ajax call

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to bind a button to a click function, get the current time and send it using ajax.

```
$("#post").click(function(){
    var mydata = {"time":current_time} //current video time
    $.ajax({
       url : "/url/to/save/comments",
       type:"POST",
       data:mydata,
       success:function(msg){}
    })
});
```